# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, listview

I have an app with differents listview with checkboxes: they are populated with a CursorAdapter.
The user can check/uncheck items and the items are stored into a **TreeSet**.
The last activity is a simple listview and it reads data from the TreeSet.

The activity are organized in tab.

The TreesSet was chosen because I needed to sort the elements in the last listview.

The problem is that,sometimes, I get this error:

*11-13 06:58:51.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1870): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099669, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class org.boggix.adapter.CalcoloAdapter)]*

Note that “CalcoloAdapter” is the adapter of the last activity.

I suspect that the problem is the TreeSet itself: it’s changing the order (as expected) of the elements inside it so, the adapter in the last activity is complaining about it.

I tried to use notifyDataSetChanghed() inside the CalcoloAdapter.onResume(),
but the error is coming before that (it occurs when I check/uncheck elements on the others listview).

How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 2):

An attemp to modify adapter/ListView from thread other that UI thread ,creates this problem .
so on Check/unckeck if you are doing some stuff's in new thread then Adapter related work should be done in UI thread only .
Use `AsyncTask`, `Handler` or `RunOnUITHread` for this .